# Symfony If Statements

Tags: php, symfony, smarty, prestashop

I am hoping to get some assistance with Symfony 'if' statements.

Essentially I am trying to do, if the price value is equal to or greater than $500, display 'Free Shipping', if otherwise, display 'Click & Collect'.

This is a for a prestashop theme and I have the below coding after the initial if statement

```
{else}
                        {if $pricediplay ==> 500} {l s='Free Shipping!'}{/if}
                    {else}
                        {if $pricediplay ==< 499.99} {l s='Click & Collect'}{/if}
                    {/if}
```

The whole coding of this part is:

```
{if $option.total_price_with_tax && !$option.is_free &&
(!isset($free_shipping) || (isset($free_shipping) && !$free_shipping))}
    {if $use_taxes == 1}
        {if $priceDisplay == 1}
                {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax}
                {if $display_tax_label}
                    {l s='(tax excl.)'}
                {/if}
            {else}
                {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_with_tax}
                {if $display_tax_label}
                    {l s='(tax incl.)'}
                {/if}
        {/if}
            {else}
                {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax}
    {/if}
{else}
    {if $pricediplay ==> 500}
        {l s='Free Shipping!'}
    {/if}
{else}
    {if $pricediplay ==< 499.99}
        {l s='Click & Collect'}
    {/if}
{/if}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cohen

Comment: What happens currently? It looks like you might have broken your braces after `{if $pricediplay => 500}`

Comment: It is producing a 500 Internal Server error when I apply the changes. I am sure I have done something wrong, just unsure what it is.

Comment: The broken braces could be causing that. Look in your error log and see what the error message is

Comment: Okay, I think I have fixed my braces now, but still no joy. I've updated the original post with the updated coding.

Comment: If you are still getting a 500 (server) error then there should be something in your error log. Have a look there

Comment: I was getting errors yesterday but now nothing.......... Going to have to do some more digging on the server end to get some errors.

Comment: Made progress and stopped the 500 internal server but now not getting my results displayed.

Comment: What are `==>` and `==<` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your posting what you're trying to achieve. i suspect the changes you want might be something like this:

```
{if $option.total_price_with_tax && !$option.is_free &&
(!isset($free_shipping) || (isset($free_shipping) && !$free_shipping))}
    {if $use_taxes == 1}
        {if $priceDisplay == 1}
            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax}
            {if $display_tax_label}
                {l s='(tax excl.)'}
            {/if}
        {else}
            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_with_tax}
            {if $display_tax_label}
                {l s='(tax incl.)'}
            {/if}
        {else}
            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax}
        {/if}
    {/if}
{else}
    {if $priceDisplay >= 500}
        {l s='Free Shipping!'}
    {/if}
{else}
    {if $priceDisplay <= 499.99}
        {l s='Click & Collect'}
    {/if}
{/if}
```

In `smarty` the comparison operators are like in many languages `>=` and `<=`. `=>` has a different meaning in PHP, and smarty is translated into PHP before execution.

Comment: I want to achieve that if the pricedisplay is greater than or equal to $500 that that it shows 'Free Shipping'.

If it is less than or equal to $499.99, that it shows 'Click and Collect'

I have done as per your coding example, but no luck. I think it is the configuration of the greater than '==>' which produces a 500 internal server error.

Comment: If `500` is where it occurs, maybe change that to:`500.00` I mean add the 2 decimal places.

Comment: Still no joy. I need to try and get the greater than or equal to configuration correct.

Comment: I just noticed something. You've written it as `$pricediplay` instead of `$priceDisplay`. Maybe that's the change you need. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I did fix that up, but no success with that either.

Comment: I updated my post. Try `if $priceDisplay => 500}` as well.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error again.

Comment: Is there the possibility of a 'between function'

If between 1 and 499.99 do x
If between 500.00 and 100000000 do y

Comment: I'm not sure how this language works. I've never seen it before with the brackets. I'm wondering if you have more than one `else`, then you may need to use `elseif` instead??? Again, i'm not certain.

Comment: Yeah, it is a very weird language........ and confusing. First time using it as well. I have some ideas and slowly learning it however ran into this problem.

Comment: Ah, maybe the greater than needs to be before the equals, like so: `{if $priceDisplay >= 500}`. Can you try? i saw that in the docs: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to be a template using twig if statements must be written as follow:

```
{% if ... %}
    //your own logic...
{% endif %}
```

You can use both :

```
{% elseif ... %}
{% else %}
```

to make different cases.

You can set variables like this:

```
{% set var='toto' %}
```

and display a variable like this:

```
{{ var }}
```

And finally comparison operators are written as they are pronounced:

- greater than or equal : >=
- less than or equal : <=

Comment: Thanks Olivier, is the below correct?
`{% set var="500" %}


{% if $priceDisplay == 1 %}

 {% if $priceDisplay >= {{ var }} %}
        'Free Shipping!'
    {% endif %}
 
 {% elseif %}
        'Click & Collect'
 {% else %}

{% endif %}`

Comment: {% if $priceDisplay >= var %} 'Free Shipping!' {% else %} 'Click & Collect' {% endif %}. In your example var will be a string and not an integer, It that what you want ? If not then you must write {% set var=500 %} (without quote)